# How to exclude a certain value from a column on my selection

Tags: sql

[image]

I have a table that looks like this.

And I want to create a table that shows me the Machine_ID and Run_ID for all runs that contained Alarm_1 but did not contain Alarm_4

Therefore I want something to show me

[image]

I am just not sure of how to do this because if I say "Show rows where Alarm_Name!= Alarm_4" then it is going to show me the runs that have EAlarm_1, Alarm_2 and Alarm_3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT t1.machine_id, t1.run_id
FROM tablename t1
WHERE t1.alarm_name = 'Alarm_1'
  AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM tablename t2
    WHERE t2.machine_id = t1.machine_id AND t2.run_id = t1.run_id AND t2.alarm_name = 'Alarm_4'
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

> Machine_ID and Run_ID for all runs that contained Alarm_1 but did not contain Alarm_4

Aggregation and `having` come to mind:

```
select machine_id, run_id
from t
where alarm_name in ('Alarm_1', 'Alarm_4')
group by machine_id, run_id
having min(alarm_name) = 'Alarm_1' and max(alarm_name) = 'Alarm_4';
```

Because `'Alarm_1' <` 'Alarm_4'`, you can simplify the` having` clause to:

```
having max(alarm_name) = 'Alarm_4'
```